# To not use ASP.NET Identity Framework 2.0 default tables

Tags: asp.net, frameworks, owin, identity, asp.net-mvc-5

I do not want to use the default ASP .NET 2.0 Identity tables (AspNetUsers, AspNetRoles, AspNetUserClaims, AspNetUserLogins, AspNetUserRoles) but still want to use OWIN. Is there a way to prevent these tables from getting created in the database automatically at all while creating a web application on MVC .NET?

Answer (score 0):

These tables are being created because your `ApplicationDbContext` inherits from `IdentityDbContext<TUser>` from `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework`.

Remove this inheritance and the ASP.NET Identity tables will not be created.